# Spacing between figures in \matrix of tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, tikz-node

I'm trying to put 4 figures with unequal heights in a matrix. My code which you can compile [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kxnxhdmxmrtd) is:

```
\documentclass[journal=aamick]{achemso}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\title{hi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newlength{\w}
\setlength{\w}{.9\paperwidth}

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]

\matrix[column sep=.0\w,row sep=.0\w,%
every node/.style={draw,node distance=0 and 0,outer sep=0},xshift=-.048\w]{
\node [label=above:(a)] (a)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{figs/16_4.jpeg}}; & 
\node [label=right:(d)] (d)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{figs/16_10.jpeg}};\\
\node [label=below:(b)] (b)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{figs/8_4.jpeg}}; &
\node [label=right:(c)] (c)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{figs/8_10.pdf}};\\};

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

What I'm getting is:

[image]

which has a gap (the red arrow) between the left boxes. What I want is sth like:
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: You can also use a tabular and \raisebox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set the anchors appropriately, i.e. add

```
row 1/.style={anchor=south},row 2/.style={anchor=north}
```

to the options of the matrix.

```
\documentclass[journal=aamick]{achemso}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\title{hi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newlength{\w}
\setlength{\w}{.9\paperwidth}

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\matrix[column sep=.0\w,row sep=.0\w,%
every node/.style={draw,outer sep=0},
row 1/.style={anchor=south},row 2/.style={anchor=north}]{
\node [label=above:(a)] (a)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{example-image-duck}}; & 
\node [label=right:(d)] (d)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w,height=.14\w]{example-image-duck}};\\
\node [label=below:(b)] (b)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w]{example-image-duck}}; &
\node [label=right:(c)] (c)  {\includegraphics[width=.14\w,height=.14\w]{example-image-duck}};\\};

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not have your graphics files, so I use some standard files, but with different effective heights to simulate your problem.

**ADDENDUM**: You can save a few key strokes by using

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.14\w}
```

since then all the widths of included graphics in this group will have this width. Also `nodes` is an abbreviation for `every node/.append style`, and  `node distance=0 and 0,` does not have any effect, nor does `,xshift=-.048\w` as long the `tikzpicture` consists of only this matrix.

```
\documentclass[journal=aamick]{achemso}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\title{hi}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newlength{\w}
\setlength{\w}{.9\paperwidth}

\noindent \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=.14\w}
\matrix[column sep=.0\w,row sep=.0\w,%
nodes={draw,outer sep=0},
row 1/.style={anchor=south},row 2/.style={anchor=north}]{
\node [label=above:(a)] (a)  {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; & 
\node [label=right:(d)] (d)  {\includegraphics[height=.14\w]{example-image-duck}};\\
\node [label=below:(b)] (b)  {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}}; &
\node [label=right:(c)] (c)  {\includegraphics[height=.14\w]{example-image-duck}};\\};

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: they provides their graphics in the link to overleaf, https://www.overleaf.com/read/kxnxhdmxmrtd

Comment: @AlexRecuenco Thanks! But first of all I do not have an overleaf account, then the link may disappear and finally the answer is meant to work for everyone without the of downloading the graphics. The answer will work for the OP, too, all they need to do is to add `row 1/.style={anchor=south},row 2/.style={anchor=north}` to the options of the matrix.

Comment: that is a great point!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)
By the way, do you know a way to avoid repeating [width=.14\w] for all the \includegraphics somehow?

Comment: The `width=...` is just to simulate your picture width and height difference, you can ignore that.

Comment: @AlexRecuenco. Yes, what I mean is, if there is a way to write that once somewhere and have it applied to all the \includefigures in the \matrix.

Comment: @AlexRecuenco Yes. Add `\setkeys{Gin}{width=.14\w}`. If you add it within the `tikzpicture`, only the graphics inside the picture will be affected.

Comment: @Ali I added this to the answer as an addendum.